# call gwt service without gui

Tags: gwt, servlets

someone has some experiences/recommendations in mixing gwt & servlets ? on client-side it's not always possible to use gwt-gui to invoke remote-service. for example: on clientside code you can click a button to retrieve data & render it on page , if i  do a normal GET from java-script or from firefox-addon, which needs to be pointed to a normal servlet. is there a way for this GET to invoke gwt-service ?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT RequestFactory

here is tutorial

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html

http://javaasylum.blogspot.com/2010/11/gwt-21-request-factory.html

or you can call HTTP.GET request

http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.http.client.html

Comment: thanx. gwt.http.client is the thing i'm looking for